# How to dismiss Snackbar when user does any action?

Tags: android, dismiss, snackbar, indefinite

I can show snackbar like this.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("action", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ...
            }
        });
snackbar.show();
```

My snackbar has indefinite length and I want it. But When user does any action, such as scrolling screen or touching screen/view, I want to dismiss snackbar. I can find some library and codes but they are so complicate. Is there not easy way to dismiss snackbar?

Comment: Try to use [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are using fragments, so you could set an onTouchListener to your fragments main layout, and put inside snackbar.dismiss().

if you just want to dismiss on scroll set an onScrollListener and in the event dismiss the snackbar, Here's an implementation for recyclerview onScroll:

```
list.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) 
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

use `dismiss()` to close a snackbar programatically.

In Kotlin, create a null-safe variable because dismiss() crashes when null

```
var snack : Snackbar? = null
```

create a snackbar inside a button click with (view: View) or if it's in the menu, replace `view` with findViewById(android.R.id.content)

```
   snack = Snackbar.make(view, "tell something", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(null, null)
   snack.show()
```

then close it from other button click

```
snack.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found solution. I add framelayout in my view group. thank you dieter_h

Creating custom Framelayout class for override IntercepterTouchEvent

```
private class InterceptTouchEventLayout extends FrameLayout {

    Snackbar mSnackbar;

    public InterceptTouchEventLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    public void setSnackbar(Snackbar snackbar) {
        mSnackbar = snackbar;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mSnackbar != null && mSnackbar.isShown()) {
                    mSnackbar.dismiss();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

my xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    ...>
    <ScrollView .../>
    <FrameLayout .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

Getting FrameLayout which is top of it by

```
View contentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View framLayout = ((ViewGroup) contentView).getChildAt(0);
```

Writing method for adding custom layout

```
private void addInterceptLayoutToViewGroup(Snackbar snackbar) {
    View contentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) contentView).getChildAt(0);
    if (!(vg.getChildAt(0) instanceof InterceptTouchEventLayout)) {
        InterceptTouchEventLayout interceptLayout =
                new InterceptTouchEventLayout(this);
        interceptLayout.setSnackbar(snackbar);
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = vg.getChildAt(i);
            vg.removeView(view);
            interceptLayout.addView(view);
        }
        vg.addView(interceptLayout, 0);
    } else {
        InterceptTouchEventLayout interceptLayout = 
                (InterceptTouchEventLayout) vg.getChildAt(0);
        interceptLayout.setSnackbar(snackbar);
    }
}
```

So, I can use like this!!!

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("action", new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //...
            }
        });
snackbar.show();
addInterceptLayoutToViewGroup(snackbar);
```

Honestly, My solution changes the view tree(?). After that, My xml may be..

```
<FrameLayout
    ...>
    <InterceptTouchEventLayout
        ...>
        <ScrollView .../>
        <FrameLayout .../>
    </InterceptTouchEventLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```